# Transpose SQL from specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: I have the following table]

[image: This is my desire result]

This is my query:

```
SELECT 

DOC_DATA.doc_id AS "doc_id",
DOC_DATA.data_value + '  -  ' + DOC_DATA_1.data_value AS "data_value",
DOC_DATA.stamp_date AS "stamp_date",
DOC_DATA.stamp_uid AS "stamp_uid"

FROM 

P2P.dbo.doc_data DOC_DATA,  
P2P.dbo.doc_data DOC_DATA_1 

WHERE 

DOC_DATA.doc_id = DOC_DATA_1.doc_id
AND ( DOC_DATA.data_index = 64
AND DOC_DATA_1.data_index = 65) 

ORDER BY 

1
```

But I keep having only "doc_id" that have a value for 64 and 65, I actually want all the "doc_Id" including the ones with no value for 64 and 65

Comment: First - Don't post data as pictures. Second - please tag correct DBMS, is it `mysql` or ` sql-server`? Can't be both..

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select dd.doc_id,
       max(case when dd.data_index = 64 then data_value end) as de_code,
       max(case when dd.data_index = 65 then data_value end) as de_description
from P2P.dbo.doc_data dd
group by dd.doc_id;
```